# Air conditioner broke after putting to much washer fluid

Tags: noise, ac, nissan, versa

I have a Nissan Versa 2012, the air conditioner stopped working and is giving a hissing sound after I put too much washer fluid in the reservoir. I mean two events have to be related as it happened exactly after that what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Those two systems are not linked.

Perhaps an a/c pipe was corroded and finally broke when you closed the hood for example.

This sounds like coincidence, but you will need to fix it.